# HTTPD LDAP Authentication not working

Tags: ldap, httpd, openldap, httpd.conf, mod-auth-ldap

First time trying to do this and I'm completely lost.

I have a Oracle Linux 7.9 server that has a directory that needs to be shared to users via HTTP so that they can download files to send out to third parties.

I have been easily able to make it visible and open to all, but I have so far been unable to get LDAP to work - it won't even prompt me for credentials.

I have done a yum install for: httpd, openldap, openldap-clients, nss_ldap and mod_ldap (as per instructions found in assorted articles over the web).

I have edited /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and added

```
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
```

(httpd log shows that these are already loaded and it skips it anyway).

In /etc/httpd/conf.d/interfaces.conf I have the following (edited for security):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin user@mycompany.com
  ServerName mywebserer
  ServerAlias x.x.x.x
  DocumentRoot /

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog "logs/interfaces_prd_webdav_error_log"
  CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/webdav_access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M" "%t %h  \"%r\" %>s %b"

  LimitXMLRequestBody 131072
  DavLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb

# ************************************************************

  <Directory "/directory/to/export">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Use Your App Login"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://mydomain.local:389/ou=OU1,ou=MyBusiness,dc=mycompany,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
    AuthLDAPBindDN "ldapsearchuser"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret_password"
#    Require group cn=group,ou=Groups,dc=mycompany,dc=local
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>

  Alias /files /directory/to/export

  <Location /files>
    Dav on
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

"Require group" is commented out because at this stage I'm just trying to get the initial credentials challenge made and validated.

If it matters the server I'm connecting to is a Linux OpenLDAP server, not a Microsoft AD.

When I go to http://x.x.x.x/files - It just gives me the contents of the directory, no challenge for credentials.

I checked /var/log/httpd folder after the most recent access (after removing existing logs) and nothing had been added to any log files.

When restarting httpd the error_log shows:

```
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:00.277230 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11681] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:01.345552 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 15751] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:01.357475 2021] [so:warn] [pid 15751] AH01574: module ldap_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:01.357497 2021] [so:warn] [pid 15751] AH01574: module authnz_ldap_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::221:f6ff:fe6e:9c69. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:01.383713 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 15751] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:01.387200 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15751] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 () configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:01.387228 2021] [core:notice] [pid 15751] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

When attempting to access the directory via a browser I get:

In interfaces_prd_webdav_error_log (not overly concerned about this atm I don't think):

```
[Tue Jul 13 17:07:20.015412 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 15754] [client 10.1.7.44:55820] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /favicon.ico, referer: http://172.17.9.21/files/
```

In webdav_access_log:

```
[13/Jul/2021:17:07:19 -0400] 10.1.7.44  "GET /files/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1303
[13/Jul/2021:17:07:20 -0400] 10.1.7.44  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
```

Anyone able to offer any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either a problem with logging or you're not reaching this virtualhost or Apache isn't using this config (forgot to reload or restart?)

Comment: Definitely restarted httpd - I know it's using this config because before I added "Options +Indexes" I was getting a message that  directory listing was forbidden by server config.

Comment: Logging is probably also working since the error logs picked up the previous message before I added the Options bit.  It's almost like I've not turned something on to trigger the call to check credentials.

Comment: So "nothing had been added to any log files" was a typo?

Comment: Well, after I fixed that particular issue....   Webdav access log shows this: 
```[13/Jul/2021:16:13:26 -0400] 10.1.7.44  "GET /files/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1303
[13/Jul/2021:16:13:26 -0400] 10.1.7.44  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
```

Comment: When restarting, nothing worthwhile in the error logs?

Comment: And when d'loading a file, still no auth?

Comment: Edited question to show contents of logs.  Can download anything I want without auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it's been solved.

I changed the Location section to just

```
  <Location /files>
    Dav on
    Options +Indexes
  </Location>
```

And now it's working.  It appears to be that the other pieces there were overriding the AD config.

Thanks for your comments though, Gerald.